# File Upload with single Button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have imlepmented file upload with one button
i have taken one button and one file upload control and on clicking the button i am opening file upload for browsing file,

after selecting file i have to submit the form, the problem is arising when i click on submit,the file upload gets empties and i got HttpPostedFileBase null in my controller,but when i directly use file upload control(ie clicks on its browse button) its working fine

Below is my code

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            $("#logup").click();
            $("#logup").select();
            return false;
        });

    });




<input type="button" id="btn" value="Choose file" />
<input type="file" id="logup" name="logofile" style="display:none" />


<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

2nd i also wants to show file name after selecting the file, besides my btn how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer To Question 1**

Below is a form with two submit buttons. Note that both these submit buttons have the same name i.e “submitButton”

```
@Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController"); %>
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Button1" />
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Button2" />
}
```

Now over to the Controller, the Action takes in an input parameter called string stringButton and the rest is pretty self-explanatory.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string submitButton) {
        switch(submitButton) {
            case "Button1":
               // do something here
            case "Button2":
               // do some other thing here
            default:
                // add some other behaviour here
        }
...
}
```

**Answer To Question 2**

You will be getting fileName from [HttpFilePostedBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx) object, but since you dont want a post back, you can create an action thats return this value as `JSON`

Comment: should i've to make btn as submit??